# SQL Query to extract ranges from a numeric column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to extract ranges from a number column that has several gaps between the numbers

```
81 
82 
83                  Expected Result
null                Range1 - 81 to 83
86                  Range2 - 86 to 89
87                  Range3 - 95 to 97
88 
89 
null 
95 
96 
97
```

I'm tring to figure a way to group each block and get min and max values

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract a sequence and then aggregate:

```
select min(col) as range_start, max(col) as range_end
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum
      from t
      where col is not null
     ) t
group by (col - seqnum);
```

If you want to enumerate the ranges, you can add:

```
row_number() over (order by min(col)) as range_num
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=848fab8896e6425ff4947e30dabf5ae2) is a db<>fiddle.